xero-node `refreshTokens` returns `401`
My app has an integration with Xero using the xero-node SDK. I can complete the Xero authentication process using the OAuth workflow without issues and the token set returned by Xero is stored in my database. However, once the access_token has expired (after 30 minutes) and the tokens need to be refreshed, invoking the xeroClient.refreshToken function is failing with the xero API request returning 401.
This is an excerpt of the code from my API route that handles fetching the existing Xero token set, checking if it's expired and if it's expired, invoke a helper function that refreshes the token:
const xero = createXeroClient();

    /** check for existing tokenSet in db (xero will return existing tokenSet if org is already connected) */
    let existingTokenSet = await getXeroTokenSet(userId, clientUser.client_id);
    console.log("existing tokens returned");
    /** if tokenSet already exists, check if its expired */
    if (existingTokenSet) {
      console.log("if statement exec");
      /** Token needs to be set in the xero client, even if it's expired - required for xero.refreshToken func */
      await xero.setTokenSet(existingTokenSet);
      await xero.initialize();

      xero.updateTenants(false);
      console.log("update tenants called");

      console.log("token from database", existingTokenSet.refresh_token);
      console.log(
        "check db token expired",
        isXeroTokenExpired(
          existingTokenSet.created_at,
          existingTokenSet.expires_in
        )
      );

      const expired = isXeroTokenExpired(
        existingTokenSet.created_at,
        existingTokenSet.expires_in
      );

      if (expired) {
        console.log("read tokens expired");

        existingTokenSet = await handleXeroTokenRefresh({
          xeroClient: xero,
          refreshToken: existingTokenSet.refresh_token,
          userId,
          clientId: clientUser.client_id,
        });


        console.log("refreshed token returned");

        await xero.setTokenSet(existingTokenSet);
        await xero.updateTenants(false);
      }

This is the helper function that refreshes the tokens, and updates the token set stored in the database:
export const handleXeroTokenRefresh = async ({
refreshToken,
userId,
clientId,
xeroClient,
}: {
refreshToken: string;
userId: string;
clientId: number;
xeroClient: XeroClient;
}) => {
try {
  const refreshTokenSet = await xeroClient.refreshToken().catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error refreshing xero token");
    throw error;
  });

  console.log("Token set received:", refreshTokenSet);

  const validationResult = createXeroTokenSchema.safeParse({
    ...refreshTokenSet,
    expires_in: refreshTokenSet.expires_in,
    user_id: userId,
    client_id: clientId,
  });

  if (!validationResult.success) {
    console.error("Validation error:", validationResult.error);
    throw new Error("Error validating xero token set");
  }

  await deleteXeroToken({ userId, refreshToken, clientId });

  const newTokenSet = await createXeroTokenEntry(validationResult.data);
  console.log("Refreshed token set successfully");
  return newTokenSet;
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error refreshing xero tokens: ", error);
  throw error;
}
};

This is the error returned by xeroClient.refreshToken():
outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: false,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /connections HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Bearer <redacted>' +
        'User-Agent: axios/1.7.2\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
        'sentry-trace: 0347fa069ac24d93b8917fe33e4ded1c-b81bcb29bbbe68f2-0\r\n' +
        'baggage: sentry-environment=production,sentry-release=8c0a8d397c87185f2e8f481e427b30f86ff58992,sentry-public_key=7eb42c47637793b35e511de17cd63f43,sentry-trace_id=0347fa069ac24d93b8917fe33e4ded1c\r\n' +
        'x-vercel-id: <redacted>' +
        'Host: api.xero.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/connections',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'api.xero.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
      [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
    },
    data: {
      Type: null,
      Title: 'Unauthorized',
      Status: 401,
      Detail: 'TokenExpired: token expired at 07/23/2024 04:34:24',
      Instance: '7c4e4c62-e326-4e35-9f33-40c387542c5a',
      Extensions: {}
    }
  }
}

Any help is appreciated!

If you haven't done so already, please can you contact Xero Support here and include your app's client id, and the instance id from the most recent error message
